# Renaming quick launch links and list headers not updating for other users

Tags: quick-launch, rename

I have a problem that i can't seem to find any solution for.

We're using Sharepoint Online and have the publishing feature enabled.

I am the full site admin.

If i rename links in the quick launch bar either directly in the menu or via Navigation in Site Settings, the link is only renamed for my user. For all other users it keeps it old name.

The same applies to list titles on pages.

If i add a list to a page and renames the list title, then on my user it'll have the new name while on all other users it will just be "ListName"[1] where "ListName" is the name of the list.

It doesn't matter if i check in and out on the page.

Why is this? And how to i make my changes permanent for ALL users?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem:

My user was displaying our sharepoint site in english while all other users used danish. So my changes only applied to the english version of our sharepoint site!

After i removed english as an alternative language, my user reverted back to danish and now i can rename stuff again.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem.
Multi language was disabled (by default) on my site. It's a bug.

Solved it by going to:

1. Site Settings > Language Settings > ENABLE
2. Choose a Language and SAVE
3. Remove the added Language and SAVE and DISABLE Language Settings

Make sure you MAKE A BACKUP of the Site Menu you want to keep. Because one of them is going to be removed!!